# Audio sync issue while converting h264 video and ADTS-AAC audio into MPEG2 TS

Tags: audio, video, mpeg2-ts

I have written a code for converting the H264 video and ADTS AAC audio into MPEG2 TS format. Everything is working except the audio sync. The sync is losing after around 20 seconds.
I have used the following formulas for calculating PTS values.

video pts = (frame count * 90000)/frame rate(20fps)
Audio pts = (frame count * 1024 *90000)/sample rate(8000hz)

Please help me to resolve this sync issue...

Comment: How many channels in audio?

Comment: Only one channel

Comment: PTS calculation seems correct to me. How do you perform audio/video TS packets interleaving with PCR packets? Further, did you try to use more players (vlc, ffplay,...)?

Comment: I recommend you to use TS validation/examination programs to see what is happening (e.g.: DVBInspector).

Comment: Converting by my own code in c. The audio sample rate is 8000 but im getting audio at every 128ms.So here 128*8= 1024 ms. Is this extra 24 ms causing the issue? If yes, could you please suggest any  better method to resolve the issue?

Comment: 128ms seems correct as `samples_in_frame / sampling_rate == 1024 / 8000 == 0.128s`. Maybe you don't correctly handle information about sampling rate in AAC elementary descriptor in TS. I again recommend you to use some TS validation tool.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.